# Download large file with WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, streaming

I have a wcf service on one side and an mvc website on the client side. I need to download a file from the server which wcf resides to mvc client, then user can download the file from the web application. I have a `LinkStream` message contract on wcf. The file represented by the `fileInfo` object below contains a 1 gig of data in it.

```
return new LinkStream { Stream = fileInfo.OpenRead(), Instant = true };
```

When client makes this call though I check the windows task manager on the server and I am seeing a memory usage peak there, it goes up more than 4gig then falls back to where it was and closes the connection and throws the following exception on client:

```
The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: 
'<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Overflow or underflow in the arithmetic operation.</title> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /> 
<style> 
body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;}  
p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px} 
b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px} 
H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red } 
H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon } 
pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-    size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt} 
.marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;} 
.version {color: gray;} 
.error {margin-bottom: 10px;} 
.expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; } 
@media screen and (max-width: 639p'.
```

Here are my config files on wcf and mvc side:

WCF:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding> 
    <binding name="LinkEndBinding" receiveTimeout="00:05:10" sendTimeout="00:05:30" 
             transferMode="Streamed" maxBufferSize="65536" maxReceivedMessageSize="1288490188" useDefaultWebProxy="false" >
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483646" maxStringContentLength="2147483646" maxArrayLength="2147483646" maxBytesPerRead="2147483646" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483646" />
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="Links.Links" >
    <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingName="LinkEndBinding" contract="Links.ILinks" />
  </service>
</services>  
</system.serviceModel>
```

MVC:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
 <basicHttpBinding> 
  <binding name="LinkEndBinding_ILinks" receiveTimeout="00:05:10" sendTimeout="00:05:30" transferMode="Streamed" maxBufferSize="65536" maxReceivedMessageSize="1288490188" useDefaultWebProxy="false">
   <security mode="None" /> 
   <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483646" maxStringContentLength="2147483646" maxArrayLength="2147483646" maxBytesPerRead="2147483646" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483646" /> 
  </binding>
 </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client> 
 <endpoint address="<myUrl>/Core.Links.Implementation/Links.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="LinkEndBinding_ILinks" contract="LinkService.ILinks" name="LinkEndBinding_ILinks" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Message Contract:

```
[MessageContract]
public class LinkStream : IDisposable
{
    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public bool Instant { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public Stream Stream { get; set; }

    public void Dispose ()
    {
        Stream.Close();
    }
}
```

I am really confused here. And open to any suggestions :)

Comment: Please add your message contract. I would also suggest that you remove your real url and use a placeholder.

Comment: I've added my message contract, and as you've suggested and I've missed out, I corrected the url thing. Thanks.